# ¿Como evito que un Screen Reader lea el placeholder de un input?

Tags: html, accesibilidad

en una aplicacion Angular queremos que los Screen Readers no lean el placeholder de un input, he intentado de varias formas usando: aria-label, aria-labelledby, etc., pero despues de leer la etiqueta correcta el screen reader siempre lee tambien el contenido del placeholder, ¿alguna sugerencia? aqui un ejemplo donde no queremos que el placeholder sea leido, pero si visualizado

```
<label id="phone-test" for="phoneLabel">
                      Phone
                      <abbr class="req" title="required">*</abbr>
                    </label>
                    <input
                      #phone
                      type="tel"
                      aria-required="true"
                      [attr.aria-invalid]="
                        checkoutForm.controls['phone']?.errors ? true : false
                      "
                      formControlName="phone"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="phone"
                      placeholder="xxx xxx xxx"
                      (focusout)="onPhoneChange()"
                      (keypress)="formService.blockPhoneInput($event)"
                      aria-labelledby="phone-test" />
```

Comment: es q estas usando un placeholder como máscara, idealmente el placeholder diria "telefono personal" o "telefono del negocio" el "formato" o "mascara" lo podes poner aparte con aria-hidden